# Blackberry Webwork sdk error: Invalid application archive - resource name is not valid

Tags: html, blackberry-webworks

I'm trying to deploy to device my blackberry app (webwork html5).

When I run the command from the terminal.

```
./bbwp /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp.zip
```

I got this:

[INFO]              Parsing command line options 
[INFO]              Parsing bbwp.properties 
[INFO]              Validating application archive 
[ERROR]             Invalid application archive - resource name is not valid(__MACOSX/._config.xml)

I know bb webwork sdk doesn't allow to use '-' and '_' , so I renamed every single file in my project to remove those invalid chars. But I don't have a "._config.xml" file in my project. I have a config.xml file and it is at the root of the project.

Thanks for your help.

danny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue.

Like I said before you have to remove all the chars like '-' and "_" from all your files.
When I compressed my projecto to -> myapp.zip on my MAC, it creates a hidden folder called "__MACOSX" and inside of this folder there are a lots of files with '_',  for example ._config.xml .

So I downloaded http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25497/zipcleaner . This program removes .DS_Store files and other resource information from Finder created zip archives.

After that, I have a cleaned .zip so I compile the .zip again:

```
./bbwp /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp.zip
```

and it worked !